# Why doesn't SAS support short circuit operator?

Tags: sas, operator-keyword

Run the code in SAS
`data _null_;
    if 1 or sum(.) then put 'Hi!';
run;`
It reports missing value was generated which shows 'or' is not a short circuit operator.
Why doesn't SAS support short circuit operation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The strongest argument is for continued proper operation of all legacy SAS code, that knowingly or unknowingly rely on it.

As for the original why, that would be a question for the originators. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAS_(software)#Origins

There may be un-documented options for causing the DATA Step compiler to generate 'optimized' code that might include shortcut evaluations.

Comment: It could also be it evaluates the `sum(.)` statement first at compile time to convert it into a value, though it may not necessarily continue going through the `or` statement after it encounters `1`. A good test would to be create an absolutely monstrous `or` statement with `1` at both the beginning and end to see how the performance compares.

Comment: Absolutely is the case that OR is not short circuit evaluated.  All resolvable parts of a compound expression are fully resolved.  Hard to find that stated explicitly in the docs though.  Expectations of non-resolution can lead to logic flow problems; conversely way too many OR parts, in rare cases, can lead to performance issues. Too many ORs can be unwrapped using `SELECT` syntax.

Comment: I think it would have to be syntax embedded directly around an expression or compound part, like square brackets mean resolution with short circuit evaluation `[ x=1 or sum(x,y,z) < 3 ]`.Otherwise, the system and session settings in effect when code written and tested can not be enforced when the plain code is passed to another system using different settings.